# Linux tools for deleting backups when they get too old?

Tags: backup, disk-usage, disk-cleanup

I was looking at SQL Server 2000 today, and it has an [argument](https://serverfault.com/questions/486985/information-on-tsql-delbkups-parameter) in the `EXECUTE` command called `-DelBkUps` for deleting backups that are of a certain age.

Does Linux have any tools for deleting backups that become too old?  I would assume it would be something that is run from a cron job of some sort, or maybe part of a larger set of tools like something in Backula.

I'm certain that something along these lines could be done with bash, but I'm looking for something a little more pre-built and widely used.

Comment: I hope your backups are on tape or otherwise on non-attached disc storage and that you keep track of how this is being rotated. And copies on disc of some material (e.g. in the form of some `.tar.xz`) for quick, but none secure, restoring should be clearly named with some timestamp in the filename. You can purge based on that timestamp

Answer (score 1):

`rsnapshot` is a perl script that uses `rsync` to create backup's of files, it can be configured to retain a count (number) of backups, eg 12 monthly backups, deletes older backups automatically.

Periods can be set in hours, days, weeks, months and as you have already guessed, it would be invoked automatically by `cron`.

I've used it to create daily snapshots of a database dump (mysql) together with the directory heirachy of `Drupal CMS`. You can read further at [rsnapshot.org](http://rsnapshot.org/)

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is such a trivial shell script, it's no surprise "pre-built" programs are scarce.

How this script works depends on how you organize your backups. If you are sure you can rely on the backup tar-ball's file-creation time-stamp, you can simply use find:

```
find /backup-dir -type f -ctime +366 -exec echo rm -f {} +
```

Will find all files older than a year and print out the command that would remove them. (You can copy/paste the output, or re-run the above without `echo`)

But file timestamps might not be 100% reliable. So, I put my backups in folders marked with a 4-digit year and a 3-digit "julian" day (nth day of year). I generate that directory with:

```
date +%Y%j
```

Then I generate a "target" timestamp for last year, and compare that string to all lexicographically lesser values:

```
DAY=$(date +%j)
YEAR=$[ $(date +%Y) - 1 ]
find /backup-dir -type d | 
  awk '/[0-9]{7}/'
  awk -F/ -v target=$YEAR$DAY '$3 < target' |
  xargs echo rm -rf
```

OK, maybe not *so* trivial. This time, the `find` prints out the directory names in the backup directory. The first `awk` can be collapsed into the second; I've separated them for clarity. It filters out any directories that aren't of the form `YYYYjjj`. The second awk splits up each line along the directory separator `/` and outputs the line if and only if the third directory component (the first being empty) is smaller than the target date. Finally, we have the pseudo-remove command as before, but using `xargs` instead of `find ... -exec ... +`.